# getElementsByName in opera, ie etc

Tags: javascript

this is my code to fix compability getElementById in ie,ff,opera etc

```
    function getId(item) {  
        if( window.mmIsOpera ) return(document.getElementById(item));
        if (document.all) return(document.all[item]);
        if (document.getElementById) return(document.getElementById(item));
    return(false);
    }
```

my question is, how about getElementsByName in ie,ff, opera..

Comment: Do yourself a favor and use a library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com).

Comment: What do you try to fix there? all these browsers support getElementById since many years(IE since V5.0, Opera since 5.12)

Comment: Since when GEBI needs fixing?

Comment: Oh, and please do not use language constructs (like `return`) with parenthesis.

Comment: What everyone else said - you need to demonstrate *why* you need to do this.

Comment: i need to get value of input type='text' from a 'form'

Comment: @Ebo the gordon: jQuery example: `$('selector_here').val()`. Seriously. Dot not do this by hand. There are lots of problems across different implementations (regarding DOM).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got the solution last night...
and to get value from text field, just add an atribut "name" in form..
like **David Dorward** said : document.nameOfForm.nameOfTextfield.value

Answer (score 2):

getElementsByTagName is supported by all major browsers:

http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html

Comment: Write your HTML to avoid having an element with a name that is the same as a different element's id and, AFAIK, all those problems go away. Better yet, avoid getElementsByName, you almost never need it. For dealing with forms, using theForm.elements.foo is a better approach.

Comment: It's a really old method, it's support in IE6 onwards and everything else. You can easily try it and said.